# ABAQUS scripting, boundary conditions on reference point

Tags: scripting, reference, abaqus, boundary

I've created a reference point and applied boundary condition to it in Abaqus GUI, but when I copied text for these commands from .rpy file to my script and run it I've got the message:

```
File "C:/...../script.py", line 110 in <module> refPoints1=(r1[8], )  KeyError:8
```

The code is as follows:

```
#Here is code for creation of reference point:
a = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly
e11 = a.instances['Part-1-1'].edges
a.ReferencePoint(point=a.instances['Part-1-1'].InterestingPoint(edge=e11[1], 
    rule=MIDDLE))
#Here is code for boundary condition assignment:
a = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly
r1 = a.referencePoints
refPoints1=(r1[8], )
region = a.Set(referencePoints=refPoints1, name='Set-1')
mdb.models['Model-1'].DisplacementBC(name='BC-1', createStepName='Initial', 
    region=region, u1=SET, u2=SET, u3=UNSET, ur1=UNSET, ur2=UNSET, ur3=UNSET, 
    amplitude=UNSET, distributionType=UNIFORM, fieldName='', localCsys=None)
```

What is the problem?

Why the code written by Abaqus throws an exception when re-run from an external script?

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Why does the code throw an exception?

In your code `KeyError:8` simply means that there is no element under such an index in the container `a.referencePoints`.

#### 2. Why did this happen?

It is possible that while working in GUI you've defined more reference points than defined by your script (because, for example, you took only part of the code written by Abaqus).

#### 3. What to do?

First of all, in Abaqus it is not preferable to access objects by their indices except when it is not possible to do it differently and/or you did the numbering manually. So, if it is possible try to access objects using coordinates (e.g. `FindAt` method can be used to find the `edge` object).

Unfortunately, in Abaqus reference points are objects of limited functionality (compared to nodes and vertices). Thus, it is better to keep track of the reference point object after it was created. You can do it by:

- defining a variable:

```
rp1 = a.ReferencePoint(
    point=a.instances['Part-1-1'].InterestingPoint(edge=e11[1], rule=MIDDLE)
)
```

- and/or creating a `Set`:

```
rp1_set = a.Set(
    name='my_RP-1_set',
    referencePoints=(a.referencePoints[rp1.id], )
)
```

> Note: the method `ReferencePoint` returns a `Feature` object, not the `ReferencePoint` object. In order to access the `ReferencePoint` you have to access it by the index, which can be found in the corresponding `Feature` object.

#### 4. Additional tips for the future.

Do not forget that in the Abaqus GUI at the bottom of the window you have a python interpreter which you can use for your tests.

For example, if you run your script in GUI you can after try and "investigate" the `a.referencePoints` container:

- check it's type:

```
type(a.referencePoints)
```

- check it's length:

```
len(a.referencePoints)
```

Such an investigation can give you a better understanding of how different objects are built in Abaqus and how you can interact with them.

Hope it will help. Good luck

Comment: Excellent answer! I'd like to add that variables such as a, g, r, or p are used in the rpy file for the masks created in the GUI, which cannot directly reproduced via a script. OP needs to refer to them by name, location, etc.